# WordPress Theme Migration Local to Live Assets Not Loading

Tags: themes, database, migration

I have a fully working custom WordPress theme built off underscores served up locally via MAMP. Normally when migrating to a live server, I move over the wp-content directory and the .sql file, find/replaced with the appropriate live url. Sometimes I have to update permalinks to get everything working properly on the live server. I have followed these steps with my current site and the theme is showing up broken. The theme image doesn't display, and no hosted assets are loading (CDN assets are coming through). I'm getting no PHP errors and the rest of the site works fine, meaning the pages all link up. I've tried this process multiple times with no success, with plugins and with plugins disabled. Default themes are loading fine.

Anyone encountered anything like this before or know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: View rendered page source. Verify everything is correct.

Comment: @MichaelEcklund page source is correct, however theme JS and CSS assets are not loading.

Comment: @go_g Did you manually change the upload url path? Is this a multisite install?

Comment: @Sven it is a single site install, and the only thing I have changed with respect to uploads is unchecking the 'organize into month & year based folders' option

Comment: Solved: this was a folder permissions issue which was fixed with a chmod to 755

Comment: @go_g Congratulations! Feel free to sum it up in an answer; other people might have the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: this was a folder permissions issue which was fixed with a chmod to the parent folder containing the affected assets. The appropriate permissions level in this case was 755.

[Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/)